# Inconsistency in output from my implementation of noncentral t CDF and R's pt()

Tags: self-study, cumulative-distribution-function, t-distribution

I am trying to implement a noncentral *t* CDF as expressed by Guenther (1978), Lenth (1989), and the Wikipedia article on the non-central *t* in R. I have got my algorithm half working: when the signs of *t* and Delta are equal, I get identical results to R's pt(), but when the signs are opposite, my results differ non-trivially.

Can you help me figure out where I am going off?

Here (minus argument validation bits) is my code:

```
PNCT <- function(t,Delta,df) {
    tolerance <- 1e-12
    Ftilde <- function(t,Delta,df) {
        Delta <- sign(t)*Delta #switch sign if t<0
        lambda <- Delta * Delta
        j <- 0
        SUM <- 0
        SUMstep <- 1
        y <- (t^2)/((t^2)+df)
        while (SUMstep > tolerance) {
            pj <- (1/factorial(j)) * exp(-0.5*lambda) * ((0.5*lambda)^j)
            qj <- ( Delta/( sqrt(2)*gamma(j + 1.5) ) ) * exp(-0.5*(lambda)) * ((0.5*lambda)^j)
            SUMstep <- (pj*pbeta(y, j+0.5, df/2)) + (qj*pbeta(y, j+1, df/2))
            SUM <- SUM + SUMstep
            j <- j+1
            }
        return(pnorm(-Delta) + (1/2)*SUM)
        }
    if (t >= 0) return(Ftilde(t,Delta,df))
    else return(1 - Ftilde(t,Delta,df))
    }
```

And here are examples showing the half-right performance of my attempt:

```
PNCT(t=2.01505, Delta=2.20582, df=5)
[1] 0.3999992
pt(q=2.01505, ncp=2.20582, df=5)
[1] 0.3999992

PNCT(t=-2.01505, Delta=2.20582, df=5)
[1] 0.0339698
pt(q=-2.01505, ncp=2.20582, df=5)
[1] 0.000155399

PNCT(t=2.01505, Delta=-2.20582, df=5)
[1] 0.9660302
pt(q=2.01505, ncp=-2.20582, df=5)
[1] 0.9998446

PNCT(t=-2.01505, Delta=-2.20582, df=5)
[1] 0.6000008
pt(q=-2.01505, ncp=-2.20582, df=5)
[1] 0.6000008
```

PS I have elsewhere attempted to implement Lenth's algorithm, both by following his published FORTRAN code, and by attempting to replicate implementations in other languages, including R's internal C version, but with even less success. For this question, I am interested in how I have gaffed the above code.

Comment: You need to undertake an analysis of this expansion, because you have assumed incorrectly that the (infinite) sum has converged once its terms are sufficiently small. Half the time that is not the case. There are other subtle errors embedded in this code. For instance it can fail in calculating `gamma` and `factorial`. It is also inefficient: by directly emulating the mathematical formulas, it performs far more calculation than needed. Since this effort is a self-study exercise, why don't you refer to a good numerical analysis text? [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/) is a great resource.

Comment: Fair enough, but not relevant to my results: convergence occurs for the example values I gave, and tricks like exp(lgamma(x)) don't alter the discrepancy, either.

Comment: I'm sorry, convergence does *not* occur in your examples: that's why you get wrong answers. You falsely detected "convergence" in the erroneous examples because the series began with very small values; you never got around to computing the much larger values later in the series. Numerical analysis is difficult and subtle. (I know, I have made plenty of mistakes in the 40 years I have been doing it.) What usually happens is you *think* you have working code and later something else blows up and you spend enormous effort tracking it back to these bugs.  Study the books: it's invaluable.

Comment: Ah, I see that I misunderstood you. And you have resolved the problem (with this example) for me: the (short term) solution being that I need to evaluate convergence for abs(SUMstep). The longer term solution is, as you rightly point out for more attentive programming.

Comment: That's not the solution: as I said, you need to analyze the behavior of the terms in the series. I believe that in the bad cases they start small, increase, and only then do they decrease. (Along the way it's possible the Gammas and factorials might overflow, which is why I also directed your attention to that issue. You don't actually need to compute either Gamma or factorial for this code, because you can update the denominators as you go along.) One good approach is to work out an upper bound for how many terms to add before you compute any of them.